# How to remove schemes from xpath request results?

Tags: xpath

I have a problem. I need to check mapping for application. We have different schemes for incoming and outgoing messages. By some reason I need to get result strings in two xpath requests (one for incoming, one for outgoing). Requests for sections are very simple: `//*:effectiveDate/*`  But I cannot compare strings, because I have below resulsts

Incoming message:

```
<unadjustedDate xmlns="http://www.fpml.org/2010/FpML-4-9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">2013-10-24</unadjustedDate>
```

Outgoing message:

```
<unadjustedDate xmlns="http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/reporting" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">2013-10-24</unadjustedDate>
```

So, you can see that diff only in schemes. How to create xpath request which will return just:

```
<unadjustedDate>2013-10-24</unadjustedDate>
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Could you clarify. So you have some application which returns two responses, two XMLs. These XMLs are defined in different namespaces. And you need to compare dates from  these responses. Am I right?

Comment: Application trasform one message to another. Message1 -> Message2 with some transformation rules. But you are right in general, I need to compare that section with dates correctly moved to similar section. It can contain several dates (ex.: unadjustedDate, unadjustedDate1, unadjustedDate2 and etc..) so I need to check that all elements moved with right values. I can compare only values of tags: normalize-space(data(//*:effectiveDate)). But also I need to compare tag names

Answer (score 0):

XPath can only select nodes, it can't change them. If your two elements are in different namespaces (the correct name for what you call "schemes"), then they will invitably come out differently when you select them using XPath. If you want to modify the data you will need to use XSLT or XQuery. Alternatively you will need to find a more sophisticated way of comparing the results.

Comment: I don't need to change it, just to get results with additional filtering

Comment: Changing the namespace of a node is very much a change, and removing a namespace declaration changes the namespace of the node.